# On macOS how can I open a gui .app hidden or off screen?

Tags: macos, user-interface

I have a cross platform need to open a gui application programmatically, but keep it hidden from the user. Effectively, I want a command line driven interface to act as a wrapper over this gui app, and insulate the end user from seeing or interacting with it. The program is from a third party, I did not write it, and I can't edit it.

I can do this one way or another on Windows, on Linux, and (in theory) on older versions of Mac, but not the most recent ones.  On Windows, I can use the native api ShellEx with a hide window parameter.  It's very easy and straight forward.  In Linux, I can can render a gui app to a virtual frame buffer (using xvfb).

On macOS, the `open` command has a `--hide` and `--background` option, but they don't have any effect (at least on this app...)

I tried changing the plist file and found that LSUIElement will hide the app from the docker, but it still shows up on the screen. LSUIPresentationMode=4 or 3 OUGHT to work for exactly this, but apparently that doesn't do anything anymore as of a few os versions ago...

I tried the approach of moving the .app off of the screen with AppleScript.  That works, but you have to manually grant permissions for such a thing to occur via System Preferences. In prior versions of Mac, those permissions could be twiddled on the fly via sqlLite (so long as you had sudo rights), but now they blocked that too.  You can only pull that off apparently through a process of disabling "SIP" and forcing a reboot.  That is totally outside the realm of what I want.

I've tried using the xvfb approach on Mac (jumping through hoops to acquire the binary they use to include stock, and now dropped), but I'm not having luck with that.  I don't think it's possible to direct a mac .app to another display is it?  A .app does not render on X11 by it's nature right?

What other clever ways might there be to hide a third party app on a mac? (and that still works in most recent os versions!)

Comment: Can you post the plist that you are using? I use the LSUIElement property to hide the app and it works, even on Mojave.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  `LSUIElement` does in fact hide the app from the dock and the title bar is hidden too.  What it does not do is take the app off the screen entirely.  I believe that is the intended behavior.  Now I thought `..PresentationMode` could totally hide the app, but that doesn't.  It seems that app might respect that, if it specifically coded for such, but it is not an automatic thing the OS imposes.

Comment: I'm happy `LSUIElement` does its part.  Now if could only make my AppleScript  change the position to off screen (without manually changing System Preferences) , then I'd be all set...

Comment: Have you tried using the `LSBackgroundOnly` key? The issue may be that the app is explicitly modifying its own presentation mode (e.g. using `-[NSApplication setActivationPolicy:]`). If so, you might have to use `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` and dyld symbol interposing to trap and prevent that, or something like that.

Comment: Yeah, did in fact try that plist option too... (I'm about 10 hours into this!)

Comment: There is any command line way to enable system event access? If only could do that, I cou dmove the app off the screen programmatically.  I'm totally fine with forcing the user to just enter their sudo password.  I already auto elevate this whole process in a cross platform manner.